# Gradle exclude specific jars from the auto generated pom.xml uploadarchives mavendeployer Help/Discuss

Tags: gradle, dependencies, pom.xml

I have the standard uploadArchives task.

```
uploadArchives {
repositories {
mavenDeployer {
```

Objective: exclude specific jars from the auto generated pom. in this case from specific weblogic jars
I have tried multiple options with pom.whenConfigured, but it completely excludes anything.

```
pom.dependencies.remove(pom.dependencies.find { dep -> dep.artifactId.contains("weblogic") })
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using the newer `maven-publish` plugin?

Comment: no, we could change but this is the currently used. if i were to use the maven-publish, how would it be used to exclude the specific jars. 

Checking the doumentation pom.withXml { } is the way to modify the generated XML - that would mean writing a bit of XPATH to find and remove the specific dependencies.

is there any other way?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't use maven publishing with Gradle up to now. I just wondered about you using the old plugin. :-)